# im receiving error moving to another screen in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

i have two screens, a chat list and it corresponding chat interface, if i initially move from chatlist to interface all works fine but i try it again i receive a screen manager error, im a beginner at this

```py
    def message_list(self): # this is the code for the Chatlist screen

        try:
            chat = DataBase().get(node="Chats")
            user = DataBase().get(node="Users")
            user_2 = DataBase().get(node="Users")
            for i in chat:
                for ii in chat[i]["clients"].keys():
                    for x in user:
                        self.profile_pics = user[x]["avatar"]
                        if ii == user[x]["friend"]["list"]["name"]:
                            for a in user_2:
                                if a == ii:
                                    self.pro_pics = user_2[a]["avatar"]
                            self.ids.chat.add_widget(
                                ListOfChat(
                                    text="  " + ii.capitalize(),
                                    secondary_text=" ",
                                    photo=user_2[a]["avatar"],
                                    on_release=lambda y, value=ii: self.link(value) # point of suspected error
                                )
                            )
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            print("No Internet Connection")
            self.connection_error_handling()

    def link(self, name):
        self.user = name
        self.manager.current = "single_chat"
```

```py
class SingleChat(Screen):
    name = StringProperty("")
    chat_input = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        self.name = self.manager.get_screen("directory").ids.message.text

    def send(self):

        global size, halign, valign, height
        if self.chat_input.text != "":
            value = self.chat_input.text
            self.chat_input.text = ""
            if len(value) < 6:
                size = .22
                halign = "center"
            elif len(value) < 11:
                size = .32
                halign = "center"
            elif len(value) < 16:
                size = .45
                halign = "center"
            elif len(value) < 21:
                size = .58
                halign = "center"
            elif len(value) < 25:
                size = .72
                halign = "center"
            else:
                size = .78
                halign = "left"
            chat_download = DataBase().get(node="Chats")
            Users = DataBase().get(node="Users")

            with open("asset/data/json/exec.json") as f_obj:
                data = json.load(f_obj)

            for user in Users:
                if Users[user]["email"] == data["email"]:
                    new_user = user
            for i in chat_download:
                client_one = chat_download[i]['clients']["client_one"]
                client_two = chat_download[i]['clients']["client_two"]
                if self.name == client_one or self.name == client_two and new_user == client_two or new_user == client_one:
                    print("here")
                    info = {
                        "header": {
                            "time": f"{time.time()}",
                            "sender": f"{new_user}",
                            "content_type": "text",
                        },
                        "body": f"{value}"

                    }
                    DataBase().post(node="Chats", node_id=i, no_of_children=4, data=info, child_3="messages",
                                    child_4=f"message{secrets.token_hex(6)}id")
            chat_download = DataBase().get(node="Chats")
            for chat in chat_download:
                message = chat_download[chat]["messages"]
                # print(message)
                for cid in message:
                    # sender = message[cid]["header"]["sender"]
                    print(message[cid]["body"])
                    # body = message[cid]["message"]
                # if sender == new_user:
                #     self.ids.message.add_widget(
                #         Command(text=f"{body}", size_hint_x=f"{size}", height="100", halign=f"{halign}"))
```

File "C:\Users\Pc\PycharmProjects\app\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1052, in on_current
screen = self.get_screen(value)
File "C:\Users\Pc\PycharmProjects\app\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1078, in get_screen
raise ScreenManagerException('No Screen with name "%s".' % name)
**kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "single_chat".**

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the error message, with full stack trace.

Comment: Where is the `single_chat` Screen defined? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You are still not showing enough code to determine what is happening. But, in general, that error message means that at the time that code is executed there is no `Screen` with the name `single_chat`. Either the `Screen` has not been created, or not added to the `ScreenManager`, or the name has not been set.